# Calculating line coordinates in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a self graphing program which draws a binary tree using Fabric.js. So far I have added draw node functions and now I am working on drawing links between the nodes, however the coordinates isn't getting calculated properly. Can anybody help me to point out what the error is? The function(node1,node2,angle) draws a node2 at 200pixels away from node1 at angle passed. I found the start points of line by following the same method I founded Circle center but just by adding circle's radius which is 20 in my case instead of 200 pixels. The end points were calculated by subtracting 20 from 200 and Hence using value 180.
This is the code that I wrote:

Code:

```
function addNode(node1,node2,angle)
{
    var intialx=parseInt(node1.get('left'));
    var initialy=parseInt(node1.get('top'));

    if(angle<180)
    {  
        var pointx =Math.abs(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*200+intialx);
        var pointy=Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*200-initialy);
        var initiallinex=Math.abs(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*20+intialx);
        var initialliney=Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*20-initialy);
        var finallinex=Math.abs(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*180+intialx);
        var finalliney=Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*180-initialy);
   }
   else
   {
       var pointx =Math.abs(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*200+intialx);
       var pointy=Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*200+initialy);
       var initiallinex=Math.abs(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*20+intialx);
       var initialliney=Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*20+initialy);
       var finallinex=Math.abs(Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*180+intialx);
       var finalliney=Math.abs(Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*180+initialy);
    }

    var x=new fabric.Circle({ radius:20,originX: 'center', originY: 'center',fill:'red'});
    var value1=String(node2);
    var text= new fabric.Text(value1, {fontSize: 10, originX: 'center', originY: 'center'});
    var group = new fabric.Group([ x, text ], {left:pointx, top: pointy, angle:0});
    canvas.add(group);
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([initiallinex, initialliney, finallinex, finalliney], {   
        stroke: 'red'
    }));
    return group;
}
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbXRB.png)